# C# Hide process window

Tags: c#, winapi, process

How i can hide or minimize window of process window after starting?

P.S RedirectStandardOutput me need.I tryed use WinAPI - `ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);`
But it's did't works too

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = processName;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
process.Start();
process.OutputDataReceived += OnDataReciever;
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

Comment: Process - it's another console application....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Run a C# console application with the console hidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/836427/how-to-run-a-c-sharp-console-application-with-the-console-hidden)

Comment: me need a acesss to read window title

Comment: I'm not a mind reader. Nothing in your question talks about the console's window title. This is a surprising requirement, too, as it's not generally useful.

Answer (score 3):

As I understand your problem the child process is a console app, based on your comment to the question. In which case set

```
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;   
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

before starting the process. Discussion of the various options can be found here: [.NET - WindowStyle = hidden vs. CreateNoWindow = true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094003/net-windowstyle-hidden-vs-createnowindow-true)

Comment: yeap i will can do it, but me need access to window title, but with now window style, it's impossible, or have any way's for it? (noWindow+ a lot of WinApi for get title text)

Comment: Not according to the question that was asked. If you want to ask about window styles that's something else altogether. I just answered the question that was asked.