# C# Ignores "ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;"?

Tags: c#, process, window, spotify, process.start

Everything else but Spotify starts up hidden. (Spotify is downloaded from the Microsoft Store)
I only wrote "spotify.exe" at `Process.Start();` because it was in the PATH.

```
static void performanceMode()
{
    //Hide Console
    Process process = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

    startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"; //Starts hidden.
    startInfo.Arguments = "/C powercfg /s 0776b752-5add-4983-8d52-f7370e479b36";

    process.Start();
    startInfo.Arguments = "";

    startInfo.FileName = "spotify.exe"; //Doesn't start hidden.
    process.Start();

    startInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Skillbrains\\lightshot\\Lightshot.exe"; //Starts hidden.
    process.Start();

    startInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\LGHUB\\lghub.exe"; //Starts hidden.
    process.Start();

}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    performanceMode();
}
```

Comment: So it is seems it's not C# but Spotify which ignores the flag, or?.

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the case but I don't understand why that would be the case...

Comment: The WindowStyle given is passed to the application's `WinMain`. What the application does with this value, is not under your control. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094003/net-windowstyle-hidden-vs-createnowindow-true